# Redshift (Postgres) RANGE Function

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have the following query that's worked in another DBMS, but I can't get it to work in Redshift.  It doesn't seem to like the range with the interval.  Any advice on how to modify it accordingly?

```
COUNT(1) OVER (partition by include_flag,grouping_dimension,requested_hour,dow ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN interval '30 days' PRECEDING AND interval '1 second' PRECEDING) as observations_grouping
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the error message? Or the unexpected result?

Comment: from what I've read, it's simply not supported in Postgres/Redshidft.  The closest thing you can do is RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING.  The error is a syntax error near "INTERVAL"

Comment: Amazon Redshift **is not** Postgres. [COUNT Window Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_COUNT.html)

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately in Redshift you can just specify the number of rows to look back/forward and not the precise condition, for a condition you can use join

```
select include_flag,grouping_dimension,requested_hour,dow,count(1)
from source_table t1
join source_table t2
using (include_flag,grouping_dimension,requested_hour,dow)
where t2.ts between t1.ts-interval '30 day' and t1.ts-interval '1 second'
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Any chance you can help me re-shape my statement into an example of what you're saying?  Thank you!